# Blank Line Seg. Fault (Writing Own Shell)

Tags: c, shell

I'm still learning about writing simple shell.

I want this shell to allow blank lines and comments.

I did some coding and I encountered a problem that if I directly just input enter (blank line), it directly seg.fault core dumped.

I don't know exactly where's the mistake, because I print everything and all seems fine. The only thing that I suspicious in these line

```
if (args[0] == NULL || !(strncmp(args[0],"#",1))) {
    exitstat = 0;
}
```

I got the args from basic split command function. The weird thing is the comments works just fine.

Below is my functions for read what user input and split them (tokenize if I'm not mistaken). They are really basic because I'm learn those functions from internet tutorial.

```
char *commandInput() {
    char *command = NULL;
    ssize_t bufsize = 0;
    getline(&command, &bufsize, stdin);
    return command;
}

char **splitLine(char *command) {
    int bufsize = 64, 
    int position = 0;
    char **tokens = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
    char *token;

    token = strtok(command, DELIMITER); 
    while (token != NULL) { 
        tokens[position] = token; 
        position++;

        if (position >= bufsize) { 
            bufsize += 64;     
            tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
        }
            token = strtok(NULL, DELIMITER); 
    }
    tokens[position] = NULL; 
    return tokens;
}
```

Anybody could help me recognize what makes it seg.fault if I enter blank line? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I used debugger (finally succeed to use it after several trial) and it turns out that the error is located at the line that I didn't expect to cause any problem (see ---UPDATE----).

They way I handle my commandInput function is in `main()` function, I write

```
int main () {
......
    char * command = NULL
    char **args;
    command = commandInput();
    args= splitLine(command);

    ------------------ UPDATE!(CAUSING ERROR IF STATEMENT) ---------------
    background = 0
    numbarguments = 0

    // Condition to check whether there is a start program running in       backgrond
    if (!(strncmp(args[numbarguments - 1], "&",1))) {
       background = 1;
       args[numbarguments - 1] = NULL;
    }

    ----------------------------------------------

    if (args[0] == NULL || !(strncmp(args[0],"#",1))) {
        exitstat = 0;
    }
    ....... //(comparing the arguments other than null)
}
```

So any advice regarding that if condition that causing me seg.fault. Thank you.

Comment: you should also check return value of realloc, it does not always succeed

Comment: Can you share your complete code which has main() to test these functions?

Comment: @cm161 yeah I just edited the thread

Comment: This `!(strncmp(args[0],"#",1)` can be simplified to `args[0]  == '#'`. As a side note, in shells, `#` is a comment even when it isn't the first character in the line. `ls -l # echo hi` yields the list of the directory but `echo hi` is never executed with or without `;` separator.

Comment: Where is `args` getting its values? Is it the 2nd parameter of `main()`? Shouldn't it be `int main(int argc, char **args)`?

Comment: @alvits sorry a little bit typo, it suppose to be `args=splitLine(command) not argument`

Comment: You could easily debug this yourself, especially since it is so easy to trigger a fault.   1.  Compile and link for the debugger (in Linux just add `-g` to the compile and link commands).  2. Enable core dumps.  3.  Run the program and cause it to fault.  4.  Run the debugger and point it to the program executable and the core dump.  5.  Display the stack.

Comment: If you are having difficulty using a debugger, you can run it with `strace -f`. It will tell you the exact signal you are getting and the calls it made from start until the segfault.

Comment: @wallyk & alvits Thank you for the suggestions. I've updated my question because I finally found the source of seg fault but I dont know how to handle it.

Comment: Okay, but which line is causing the problem?

Comment: @wallyk according to gdb, it is the update if statement

Comment: my i ask why you are not using fgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you pass to splitline is modified. strtok has the effect of modifying the string it gets by inserting \0's and returning a pointer to substrings. What strtok returns is not something you can directly store for later use, instead you need to make a copy of it.

```
 token = strtok(command, DELIMITER); 
 while (token != NULL) 
 { 
   tokens[position] = malloc(strlen(token)+1); 
   strcpy(tokesn[position],token);
...
```

so in other words it is not enough to allocate the array of pointers to strings, you also need to allocate space to hold strings that you tokenize with strtok.

---

The code

```
if (!(strncmp(args[numbarguments - 1], "&",1))) {
   background = 1;
   args[numbarguments - 1] = NULL;
}
```

looks wrong, `numberarguments` is initially 0 so you are comparing `args[-1]` with `"&"` then later you assign `args[-1] = NULL` which probably causes the seg fault.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense actually. However, it still causing seg.fault. I'm started to think, do I need to use free()?

Comment: yes you always need to free what you malloc/calloc but if you get seg fault it has nothing to do with free

Comment: I edited my question. I add another information how I handle the value from commandInput function

Comment: @CyberSpock: Which `getline()` are you referring to?  The POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) most certainly does null terminate the string it reads.

Comment: I've updated my question because I finally found the source of seg fault but I dont know how to handle it.